# Javascript function calling syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, javascript-objects

```
(function($,window,undefined) {

    $.fn.simplyScroll = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            new $.simplyScroll(this,options);
        });
    };

    var defaults = {
        customClass: 'simply-scroll',
        frameRate: 30, //No of movements per second
        speed: 2, //No of pixels per frame
        orientation: 'horizontal', //'horizontal or 'vertical' - not to be confused with device orientation
        auto: true,
        autoMode: 'loop', //auto = true, 'loop' or 'bounce',
        manualMode: 'end', //auto = false, 'loop' or 'end'
        direction: 'forwards', //'forwards' or 'backwards'.
        pauseOnHover: false, //autoMode = loop|bounce only
        pauseOnTouch: true, //" touch device only
        pauseButton: false, //" generates an extra element to allow manual pausing 
        startOnLoad: false //use this to delay starting of plugin until all page assets have loaded
    };
```

Hi I'm pretty new to javascript and the syntax, especially function wise. How would I get the value of auto in the defaults object when it's wrapped in a function like this?

I know to get auto would just be defaults.auto, but since the function isn't named I'm not sure how to even get into it. I'm planning on changing the value at a later point in an external javascript file.

Comment: You can't. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: I would imagine that you change it by passing in an object of options to the plugin. That's how it normally works.

Comment: So say I declare defaults globally? Could that work?

Comment: your `{}`s and `()`s isn't balanced

Comment: Yeah that function spans the entire file, I just took out a chunk

Comment: You could add logic to the `$.fn.simplyScroll` function that checks to see what the first parameter passed is. If it's a special string (like "getOption"), you could then look at the second parameter and return `defaults[param2]`. If a normal object is passed to the function, do what you're already doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, there are 2 ways that allows you to access to `defaults` object outside this function scope

**1.** In function scope, `defaults` object will be assigned to a propery of global object (= window)

```
...
// In the function scope
window.defobject = defaults;
...
```

For example:

```
(function($, window, undefined) {
    var defaults = {
        foo : "bar"
    };

    window.defobject = defaults;
})(jQuery, this);

console.print(defobject); // This is valid with no error
```

**2.** The function finally return this object as output

```
...
// In the function scope
return defaults;
```

For example:

```
var defobject = (function($, window, undefined) {
    var defaults = {
        foo : "bar"
    };

    return defaults;
})(jQuery, this);

console.print(defobject); // This is also valid with no error
```

Comment: Thank you for actually providing an answer to my question

Answer (score 1):

You cannot obtain this value if your code is outside of the function, unless this function stores the object in the `defaults` variable somewhere where it can be reached through a global variable.  This is due to the way that JavaScript functions work -- code external to the function has *no access* to that function's local variables.  (This is not very different from other programming languages.)

If your goal is only to change the value rather than obtain the default value, most jQuery plugins will allow you to pass in an object whose properties will override the default settings.  Based on the name of the plugin, you could do so like this:

```
$("#something").simplyScroll({
    auto: false
});
```